# screwDefaultButtons and php

Tags: php, post, radio-button

i added screwDefaultButtons plugin (http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com) to all my radio buttons and check boxes in all my forms. But i am having some problems in the server side . I am using php and when i am trying to get the post from radio buttons or check-boxes i get undefined index (other input types are working perfectly such as text inputs) .. can anyone help me please ? Below is my screwDefaultButtons code :

```
$('input:radio').screwDefaultButtons({
     image: 'url("images/radiobuttons.gif")',
        width: 18,
        height: 18
    });
    $('input:checkbox').screwDefaultButtons({
        image: 'url("images/checkboxes.gif")',
      width: 16,
       height: 16
    });
```

Here's my html code

```
    <form id="profile-form" METHOD="POST" >
            <tr>
        <td class="formLabelText">Gender</td>
        <td><div class="radioButtonCont">
        <div

 class="selectItemList"><input required type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male" checked/> Male</div>
    <div class="selectItemList"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"/> Female</div></div></td>
                                                </tr>
```

and my php :

```
if (isset($_POST['sex'])) {
        $sex = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim($_POST['sex']));
    } else {
        $sex = null;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: What's `screwDefaultButtons`?  What does that do?  Do you have a URL to its page (or its documentation)?  Also, what does your PHP look like?  Where are you getting "undefined index"?  How are you posting this form?

Comment: With the network inspector can you see the data being posted?

Comment: @slapyo no it just skipped it it doesn't even appear

Comment: That HTML is invalid.  Why do you have a `<tr>` inside a `<form>` like that?!  `<tr>`s are only valid inside `<table>`s.

Comment: Also what is `screwDefaultButtons`?

Comment: i have the form inside a table @RocketHazmat

Comment: That still is invalid HTML.  You can't have `<table><form>` that's not valid.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table  I wonder if the invalid HTML is messing up the posting of the form.

Comment: screwDefaultButtons is a jquery plugin to change the style of a radio button

Comment: but all the text fields in the form are working perfectly only the radio buttons and the checkboxes

Comment: Do you have a link to screwDefaultButtons' documentation?  Maybe you are just not using it correctly?

Comment: http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com/ @RocketHazmat

Comment: Where are you seeing "undefined index"? `isset($_POST['sex'])` shouldn't throw that error.

Comment: die(isset($_POST['sex']); is throwing this error and without die the $sex variable will be always null even if its checked